# Is there a way to identify the root DOM node for a hook's enclosing react component?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following:

```js
function useInspector() {
  // GOAL: get the DOM node for `<div>Hello!</div>`
}

function Comp() { 
  useInspector()
  return <div>Hello!</div>
}
```

I would like to access the DOM node, for the component where this hook was called.

I could do this by returning a ref

```js
function useInspector() {
  const ref = useRef(null); 
  // I expect the user to attach this ref
  return ref
}

function Comp() { 
  const ref = useInspector()
  return <div ref={ref}>Hello!</div>
}
```

But ideally, I wouldn't have trouble the user of this hook. I am guessing this is not possible, but wanted to ask, in case there's some internal react thing I could take advantage of. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a default way to do this, but you could maybe use  a wrapper component instead. Something like:

```
function Inspector({children, ...rest}) {
  const ref = useRef(null); 
  ...
  // Do what you need to do with the ref
  ...
  return <div ref={ref} {...rest}>{children}</div>
}
```

And basically instead of calling the hook use the `<Inspector>` as a wrapper where you need the functionality.
Additionally you could also let the user choose what element they want to render (so don't limit it to div) with the method described [here](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/dynamic-tag-name-props-in-react/). Like so:

```
function Inspector({children, as: Tag, ...rest}) {
  const ref = useRef(null); 
  ...
  return <Tag ref={ref} {...rest}>{children}</Tag>
}
```

and use it like

```
function Comp() { 
  return <Inspector ref={ref}>Hello!</Inspector>
}
```

or

```
function Comp() { 
  return <Inspector as={'MyCustomComponent'} ref={ref}>Hello!</Inspector>
}
```

I realise this might not be ideal for all cases but I think is the closest you can get